# При клике исчезает картинка, почему?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Здравствуйте!

[codepen.io/alex-lenk/pen/JYQMQR](http://codepen.io/alex-lenk/pen/JYQMQR) перейдите пожалуйста, и нажмите на картинку, а потом закройте всплывающее окно.

После закрытия исчезает картинка и ей присваивается `display: none`

Как исправить этот непонятный косяк?

```
$("span.fancybox2").clic(function() {
    $(this).attr('data-src', $(this).attr('data-href')).css({
        'display': 'block'
    });
});
```

Comment: а может лучше вы сюда код вставите?

Comment: Минимальный, полный, воспроизводимый пример кода должен быть в самом вопросе.

Comment: как-то вы не правильно библиотеку используете

Comment: click - пишется так

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот только что нашел правильный ответ:

```
  <span data-fancybox-href="http://test.artlenk.ru/theme/img/feature-img.jpg" class="fancybox2" rel="tag">
     <img src="http://test.artlenk.ru/theme/img/feature-img.jpg" alt="">
  </span>
```

И все будет работать! Всем спасибо, извините за беспокойство.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так будет правильно

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox2").fancybox();
});

 <a class="fancybox2" href="http://test.artlenk.ru/theme/img/feature-img.jpg"><img src="http://test.artlenk.ru/theme/img/feature-img.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

Comment: Про ссылку я знаю и сам умею. Задача стояла сделать СЕО оптимизированную всплывашку, что бы меньше ссылок было на странице.